# T/F: The taylor series of $f(x) = \frac{x}{2+x}$ around $x_{0} = 1$ as a radius of convergence $r = 4$.

Tags: calculus

T/F: The taylor series of $f(x) = \frac{x}{2+x}$ around $x_{0} = 1$ as a radius of convergence $r = 4$.

This is what I did so far: $\frac{x}{2+x} = x\cdot \frac{1}{2+x}$

Denote $t = -x -1$

Then $x\cdot \frac{1}{2+x} = -(t+1)\cdot \frac{1}{1-t} = -(t+1)\cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}t^n = -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}t^n(t+1) = -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x+1)^n\cdot x$

And I also know that this is the taylor series because if a function as a power series it must be the taylor series...

But now what?

**Edit**:

I concluded that $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n \cdot 2^n}{x^n}$ so what should I do next?

Comment: $$\frac{x}{2+x} = \frac{x}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{2}}$$ may be easier to deal with. (recall the series for $\frac{1}{1+u}$.)

Comment: what i did was also correct?

Comment: As a thumb rule, the radius of convergence is the distance from the closest singularity.

Comment: Looking at the conclusion, I doubt it. The series $\sum_n (x+1)^n$ does not converge for any $x>0$. @EricaJ.

Comment: but why? what is wrong? :( i did everything correct

Comment: It seems you substituted $t = x + 1$, rather than $t = -(x + 1)$ at some point near the end. Of course this doesn't matter for even $n$, but does matter for odd $n$.

Comment: See my edit please

Comment: I'm pretty sure $x$ should be in the numerator and $2$ in the denominator, not the other way around...

Comment: I divided every element by $x$

Comment: @EricaJ. Divided where? How? The result is not correct (if only because, well, $f(0)=0$, while your series is not even defined at $x=0$). Read my very first comment, this may help you.

Comment: $f(x) = \frac{x}{x+2} = \frac{x/x}{x/x + 2/x} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{2}{x}}$

Comment: But then you *cannot* use the power series for $\frac{1}{1+u}$. Recall that it is only valid for $\lvert u\rvert < 1$.